# Can I use browser native import in webpack 4?

Tags: webpack, dynamic-import

In some cases, I do not want to use webpack transform to dynamic import in webpack 4.

Can we do this with some options?

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const { default: Greeting } = await import("/components/Greeting.js");
  this.setState({ component: Greeting });
}
```

This `/components/Greeting.js` is precompiled on server. It works without webpack correctly in chrome.

webpack is trying to compile and emit errors

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module '/components/Greeting.js'
at webpackMissingModule
```

Answer (score 9):

@sokra (maintainer) said...

```
import(/* webpackIgnore: true */"...")
```

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7644